# HTML5 Geolocation from external GPS

Tags: html, geolocation

We have used HTML5s navigator.geolocation and found it to be very good on iOS and Android smartphones. Now the users want the same HTML5 web app to run on a laptop with external GPS.  Using Windows 7 on the laptop I just can't figure a way to share the location to a HTML5 browser (tried Safari, FF, IE, Chrome).  For testing I am using a GlobalStat BU-353 USB GPS which works standalone and I have found GPSDirect (cool freeware) to feed that signal to Win7 Sensor Location Services but still the HTML5 browsers do not see the GPS.

Anyone had any luck with this please ?

Comment: That does not depend on HTML5-features, but on how a browser accesses the GPS-device. Probably you need a browser-plugin for the device.

Comment: Thanks feeela good idea.  Haven't found anything yet but will keep looking.  Hopefully the spirit of the HTML5 Geo Location API will reach the desktop soon.

Comment: "Hopefully […] the HTML5 [GL-]API will reach the desktop soon." It has. At least Opera, Chromium and Firefox asking me questions whether to make public my current location or not. The input for the location data may inserted directly (e.g. as an address) or come from some geo-service or a device, which is capable of measuring the current geo-location…

Comment: It's all good with locations approximated from Wi-fi or IP lookup. At the moment we can get external GPS into the Windows 7 location sensor feature but there's no way to get that location to Opera, Chromium or Firefox in Windows without 3rd party software. For that reason we have now chosen GPSGate Express with 'GPS in browser' enabled and our javascript detects if GPSgate is installed on the client prior to attempting HTML5[GL-]API. Until browsers connect to the Windows 7 sensor location feature the browser plug-in is the way to go, as you say.

Comment: You've written that you've get external GPS in Winodws 7, but not in Opera, Chrome or Firefox. Does it mean that it worked under IE9?

Comment: hi @lechlukasz, none of the HTML5 browsers could use the location from the Windows 7 location sensor service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for similar solution and found this: [GpsGate](http://forum.gpsgate.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=6102).
It is standalone application which connects to almost any GPS device and publishes it's data in several forms including browsers (through Javascript API which in turn makes jsonp call to http://localhost:12175/gps/[getVersion|getGpsInfo]?jsonp=padding). It's not compatible with Geolocation API, but I think writing simple adapter shouldn't take much time. Another good thing is that it's Express edition is free for both private and commercial use ([link](http://gpsgate.com/purchase/gpsgate_express_license)).

EDIT: After some digging I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/issues/detail?id=43) patch which adds geolocation compatible adapter for GpsGate to some other geolocation library.

Answer (score 1):

Issue 45535 is beginning to address this in the Chromium feature requests. As of Jan 5 2012, the feature has been marked as "started".

Feature request: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45535

As long as you only need a single browser for your client solution (and not a universal solution) this will solve your problem.

A great method to start testing and keeping an eye out for this issue is to download Chrome Canary, which is usually 2 versions ahead of the Chrome release. I'm right now using v18 on Canary and it's great since I've been keeping an eye on the websocket schema changes.

You can find Canary here: http://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs

Comment: The experimental patchset for this has now been removed so is unlikely to be available in Chrome anytime soon - https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/22674006/